# Suggestion about how to access mysql database easily

Tags: perl

I want to know what is the **easy and simple way to access mysql database**.
I'm using Windows. Also I should be able to easily install using Active Perl's perl package manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.616/DBI.pm) and [DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-4.018/lib/DBD/mysql.pm)

For DBD::mysql for ActiveState, have a look at :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/activestate-perl.html

and

http://code.activestate.com/ppm/DBD-mysql/

Comment: I've in my windows package manager. For DBD it does not show DBD::mysql but only sqlite,oracle,odbc &csv. Yes I've installed DBI.

Comment: i'm using perl v.10 and I've checked the cpan page and it says that DBD::mysql may be there after perl v.8.0.

Comment: Very nice, I've typed this command: ppm install DBD-mysql on the cmd line rather than opening gui based ActivePerl package manager & it worked. This instruction I got from your second link. Many thanks otherwise I'd be doing in PHP.

Answer (score 3):

As [M42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372239/m42) [has said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882260/suggestion-about-how-to-access-mysql-database-easily/5882514#5882514), [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI) and [DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD::mysql) should be the basis of any work that needs to talk to a MySQL database.

But I'd go further than that and recommend that you look at [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx::Class) as an easy way to get data from (and into) a database.